# C++ Thread function calling - problem converting string to ofstream

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, type-conversion, overloading

I'm having some hard time understand the error.
I'm trying to create a vector of threads and create N amount of threads to calculate primes & write them to a file using the writePrimesToFile function.
Yet I'm having some errors while calling the function. I understand I have some type error but I can't solve it.

**Code:**

```
#include <thread>  
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip> 
#include <chrono> 
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void writePrimesToFile(int begin, int end, std::ofstream& file)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = begin; i <= end; i++)
    {
        if (checkPrime(i))
        {
            // Added: Thread lock to prevent multiple threads writing to the same file.
            mtx.lock();
            file << i << endl;
            mtx.unlock();
        }
    }
}


// Function calcualtes primes using N as the amount of threads. Output - into filePath.
void callWritePrimesMultipleThreads(int begin, int end, std::string filePath, int N)
{
    // Init Threads pool.
    std::vector<std::thread> threadVector;

    // Calcualte the margin calculation of each thread.
    // This will divide the work eaqual between the N amount of threads.
    int threadSpread = end / N; 
    int newEnd = begin + threadSpread - 1;
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open(filePath, ios::out | ios::trunc);

    // Output primes into the file.
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        threadVector.emplace_back(writePrimesToFile, begin, newEnd, file);
        begin += threadSpread;
        newEnd += threadSpread;
    }

    for (auto& t : threadVector) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Error   C2672   'invoke': no matching overloaded function found Solution
Error   C2780   'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&) noexcept(<expr>)': expects 1 arguments - 3 provided
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Ty1 &&,_Types2 &&...) noexcept(<expr>)'
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of manually locking and unlocking, use a `std::lock_guard`.

Comment: wrap `file` in `std::ref`: https://godbolt.org/z/qbc81WP8T